# What happened to WP No Category Base?

Tags: plugins, categories

What happened to the plugin in Wordpress plugin repository?

The link doesn't work:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

and search for this plugin doesn't list it.

Yes, I know I can download it from author's page, but I am intrigued why would folks at wordpress.org remove it from their list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the author of the plugin. Try again, its back now.

Comment: just out of curiosity... what happened to it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I read on some sites, it is not very pleasing performance.

Look details in the notes at bottom in [this article](http://www.vsellis.com/reviews/remove-category-from-wordpress-urls-with-wp-no-category-base-plugin-review/). (that's my reference about)

Comment: I imagine your permalink settings would affect this. Also, the Yoast SEO plugin uses similar code to do the same thing and that's still a feature of that plugin as far as I know. The code even mentions that he "borrowed" the technique from the wp no category base plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I seems to be somehow removed from the plugin repository http://wordpress.org/support/topic/my-plugins-have-disappeared

You can still find the exact code here if you like http://pastebin.com/XmZzbJKt